# Adding function templates to classes

Tags: c++, templates

So far, I have implemented a basic LinkedList. This works, but only for integers, and I would like it to work for any type.

I'm trying to get it to work for first any same type (i.e a LinkedList of just strings, or then just ints). After, I would like it to find a way of making it a LinkedList of anything (containing strings, then ints, then longs, all in one list).

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
    Node(int value);
    Node *next;
    int data;
};

Node::Node(int value){
    this->data = value;
    this->next = nullptr;
}

struct LinkedList{
    Node *head;
    LinkedList();
    void push_back(int value);
    void print();
};

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    this->head = nullptr;
}

void LinkedList::push_back(int value){
    Node *n = new Node(value);
    if(this->head == nullptr){
        this->head = n;
    } else {
        Node *cursor = this->head;
        while (cursor->next != nullptr){
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
        cursor->next = n;
    }
}

void LinkedList::print(){
    Node *cursor = this->head;
    while(cursor != nullptr){
        std::cout << cursor->data << '\n';
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    LinkedList l = LinkedList();
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.print();
}
```

The above works, however, only for ints.
I'm knew, but I think the way is to use templates, however, doing so, I seem to be doing overkill? and it doesn't compile? Is there a cleaner was to do this?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    Node(T value);
    int data;
    Node<T> *next;
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T value){
    this->next = nullptr;
    this->data = value;
}

template <typename T>
class LinkedList{
    public:
        LinkedList();
        Node<T> *head;
        void push_back(T data);
        void print();
};

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
    this->head = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::push_back(T data){
    Node *n = new Node(data);
    if(this->head == nullptr){
        this->head = n;
    } else {
        Node *cursor = this->head;
        while(cursor->next != nullptr){
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
        cursor->next = n;
    }
}
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::print(){
    Node *cursor = this->head;
    while(cursor != nullptr){
        std::cout << cursor->data << '\n';
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
}


int main(){
    LinkedList<T> *list = new LinkedList<T>();
    list->push_back(1);
    list->push_back(2);
    list->push_back(3);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Why `LinkedList<T> *list = new LinkedList<T>();` instead of just `LinkedList<T> list`? Since you don't `delete list;` you are leaking memory - and on that subject, you need `~LinkedList();` for this class to remove all the allocated `Node`s when a `LinkList` is destroyed.

Comment: *"After, I would like it to find a way of making it a LinkedList of anything (containing strings, then ints, then longs, all in one list)."* So `LinkedList<std::any>` or `LinkedList<std::variant<int, long, std::string>>`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, sorry I'm new to c++. Does the memory leak occur because once the pointer goes out of scope, the LinkedList and its nodes still occur in memory, but cannot be accessed? And I need to manually call the deconstructor, when I no longer use the LinkedList / its about to go out of scope?

Comment: @peterjwolski It'll leak because you never `delete`. The `Nodes` will still be there until your program ends (possibly because you run out of memory because you don't release the memory you've allocated). If you declare `iist` as an automatic variable (like in `LinkedList<T> list;`) it will be automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. If you instead do `new` you must also do `delete` - and the `LinkedList` destructor must do `delete` on all the `Node`s it used `new` to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring template classes, you use the "T" as a 'type placeholder' in the declaration and implementation (as you have done). However, when you want to actually *use* an object of the templated class, you replace the "T" with the *actual* type you want.

So, in your `main` (assuming you want an `int` type), you would have code like this:

```cpp
int main(){
    LinkedList<int> *list = new LinkedList<int>(); // THIS object uses "int" wherever "T" occurs in the declaration/implementation
    list->push_back(1);
    list->push_back(2);
    list->push_back(3);
}
```

I also noticed a 'possible/probable error' in your `struct` declaration, where you specified that the `data` member is of (fixed) type `int`; maybe (almost certainly, actually, as you later assign a "T"-type `value` to it) you want this to vary according to the actual type requested? If so, make the following change:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    Node(T value);
//  int data;
    T data; // Data will be whatever "T" is when an object is created.
    Node<T> *next;
};
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Push_back has problem too

Comment: @Oblivion Indeed - I'll leave that as an "exercise for the reader" (for now), as I have to dash.  Back in an hour or so.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica fair enough :)